# JavaScript Invalid or unexpected token - for long text

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, unicode

I have a very long text in a JavaScript variable. But it throws an

> Invalid unexpected token

error like below:

```
var userdetais = '<p><span style="color: rgb(75, 79, 86); font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: rgb(241, 240, 240);">মাসুদ আলম
সহ: শিক্ষক
ফরিদ উদ্দিন উচ্চ বিদ্যালয়
পো: আয়নাতলী, ডাকঘর: আয়নাতলী, শাহ্রাস্তি, চাঁদপুর-৩৬২২।
০১৭৪৮৬৮৫৪৮২</span></p>';
```

Though all the five lines are in 'userdetails' variable inside single quotation (`''`), but it recognizes only the first line. How can I put the whole text in a single variable?

Comment: The problem is because you cannot have line breaks in a string literal. It's nothing to do with the length of the text

Comment: Ops, But have to use line break, is there any way?

Comment: add \n in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
var userdetais = `<p><span style="color: rgb(75, 79, 86); font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: rgb(241, 240, 240);">মাসুদ আলম
সহ: শিক্ষক
ফরিদ উদ্দিন উচ্চ বিদ্যালয়
পো: আয়নাতলী, ডাকঘর: আয়নাতলী, শাহ্রাস্তি, চাঁদপুর-৩৬২২।
০১৭৪৮৬৮৫৪৮২</span></p>`;

console.log(userdetais);
```

**Please Note:** IE yet to support this new ES6 feature.

**OR:** If you have browser issue then use string concatenation

```js
var userdetais = '<p><span style="color: rgb(75, 79, 86); font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: rgb(241, 240, 240);">মাসুদ আলম'+
+'সহ: শিক্ষক'
+'ফরিদ উদ্দিন উচ্চ বিদ্যালয়'
+'পো: আয়নাতলী, ডাকঘর: আয়নাতলী, শাহ্রাস্তি, চাঁদপুর-৩৬২২।'
+'০১৭৪৮৬৮৫৪৮২</span></p>';

console.log(userdetais);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks brother.

Answer (score 2):

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/multiline-string-variables-in-javascript/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
- https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/es6-cool-stuffs-a-new-js-string-with-template-literals-c23a8af11b2
- https://github.com/Matt-Esch/string-template

(This whole thing is **template string** , and you can search for it by the same title )

This works:

```
var htmlString = "<div>This is a string.</div>";
```

This fails:

```
var htmlSTring = "<div>
  This is a string.
</div>";
```

Sometimes this is desirable for readability.

Add backslashes to get it to work:

```
var htmlSTring = "<div>\
  This is a string.\
</div>";
```

but generally this approach would be more clear :

```
var strText = `সহ: শিক্ষক ...`;
var strTemplate = `...<span>#{strText}</span>...`;
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer

Answer (score 0):

You must to use the line break with HTML tag

Try this:

```
var userdetais = '<p><span style="color: rgb(75, 79, 86); font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: rgb(241, 240, 240);">মাসুদ আলম <br> সহ: শিক্ষক <br> ফরিদ উদ্দিন <br> উচ্চ বিদ্যালয় <br> পো: আয়নাতলী, ডাকঘর: আয়নাতলী, শাহ্রাস্তি, চাঁদপুর-৩৬২২। <br> ০১৭৪৮৬৮৫৪৮২</span></p>';
```